# How can I improve the speed of a query on a 20 million+ row table?

Tags: mysql, index, performance, index-tuning, query-performance

I have a query that is used for getting internet traffic statistics of certain IP addresses.

There are separate IP address fields for `hosts` and blocks of IPs called `assignments`. The data is stored in 5 minute intervals.

The query results are grouped on the time column, and the total SUMs in and out of these 5 minute intervals are used to plot a graph.

The table is called `traffic` and contains (at the end of the month) around 21 million records.

```sql
SHOW CREATE table traffic:
CREATE TABLE `traffic` (
  `type` enum('v4_assignment','v4_host','v6_subnet','v6_assignment','v6_host') NOT NULL,
  `type_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time` int(32) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `bytesin` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `bytesout` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  KEY `basic_select` (`type_id`,`time`,`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

```sql
SELECT traffic.time, SUM(traffic.bytesin), SUM(traffic.bytesout) FROM traffic 
WHERE (
    ( traffic.type = 'v4_assignment' AND type_id IN (231, between 20 to 100 ids,265)) OR 
    ( traffic.type = 'v4_host' AND type_id IN (131, ... a lot of ids... ,1506))) 
    AND traffic.time >= 1343772000 AND traffic.time < 1346450399 
GROUP BY traffic.time
ORDER BY traffic.time;
```

The following is `explain` output for the query above:

```
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | traffic | range | basic_select  | basic_select | 8       | NULL | 891319 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+

show indexes from traffic;
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name     | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| traffic |          1 | basic_select |            1 | type_id     | A         |       13835 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| traffic |          1 | basic_select |            2 | time        | A         |    18470357 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| traffic |          1 | basic_select |            3 | type        | A         |    18470357 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

This query takes from 30 seconds to 30 minutes to complete. I hope I can improve things using better indexes, or maybe using a different query, but I'm unable to figure it out.

**UPDATE:**

Following the advise of the helpful commentors, I've created a primary key and added the index `traffic_pk (time, type, type_id, id)`.   Unfortunately, it turns out the cardinality of this new index is equal/lower than my original index (basic_select) and MySQL still uses my original key.

**UPDATE 2:**
I dropped my original index `basic_select` and now the `EXPLAIN` shows a higher `rows` value, but less steps in the `EXTRA` fields. Also the query execution time went down to below a minute! (still a bit too slow, but a major improvement!).

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE traffic_test \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: traffic_test
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `traffic_test` (
  `traffic_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` enum('v4_assignment','v4_host','v6_subnet','v6_assignment','v6_host') NOT NULL,
  `type_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time` int(32) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `bytesin` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bytesout` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`time`,`type`,`type_id`,`traffic_id`),
  KEY `traffic_id_IDX` (`traffic_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24545159 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The indexes on the table:

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM traffic;
+--------------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name       | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| traffic_test |          0 | PRIMARY        |            1 | time        | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| traffic_test |          0 | PRIMARY        |            2 | type        | A         |       38412 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| traffic_test |          0 | PRIMARY        |            3 | type_id     | A         |    24545609 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| traffic_test |          0 | PRIMARY        |            4 | traffic_id  | A         |    24545609 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| traffic_test |          1 | traffic_id_IDX |            1 | traffic_id  | A         |    24545609 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+--------------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

Also I simplified the query by not using the `OR`:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE traffic.time, SUM(traffic.bytesin), SUM(traffic.bytesout) 
FROM    traffic
WHERE traffic.type LIKE 'v4_host' AND type_id IN (131,1974,1976,1514,1516,2767,2730,2731,2732,2733,2734,2769,2994,2709,1,4613,4614,4615,4616,326,1520,2652,1518,1521,1522,1523,1524,1525,2203,1515,1513,1467,1508,1973,1510,1975,1511,1475,1476,1468,1469,1470,1471,1472,1473,1500,1507,1478,1480,1481,1482,1483,1484,1485,1479,1486,1487,1488,1489,1490,1491,1495,1499,1494,2269,1474,1519,2204,2976,1922,1493,1492,1497,1496,1498,1501,1502,1503,1526,1509,1506) 
AND traffic.time >= 1342181721 
AND traffic.time < 1343391321 
GROUP BY traffic.time ASC;
```

Old Execution of this query:

```
3980 rows in set (6 min 15.27 sec)
```

New Executiontime:

```
3980 rows in set (24.80 sec)
```

EXPLAIN output:

```
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | traffic | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 12272804 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
```

The rows value is still quite high. I think I can improve on this by switching the order of `type` and `type_id` in the index since there are only 4 types possible and many more type_ids.

Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: cut out columns in the table that don't correspond to your query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Table partitioning

Because of the [AND traffic.time >= 1343772000 AND traffic.time < 1346450399] clause, I imagine that you never delete data from this table, or that the table is currently storing data for multiple months.
The values in the column [time] seem to be unix timestamps (1346450399 = Fri, 31 Aug 2012 21:59:59 GMT)
Partition the table based on time column. That will speed up the data retrieval, as the DB will scan the coresponding partition (much faster then to scan whole table).

- A great partitioning tutorial can be found here: the http://www.arachna.com/roller/spidaman/entry/scaling_rails_with_mysql_table
- You will need to calculate the timestamp ranges for that, but it should not be hard to do.
- Ex: (1346450399 - 1343772000) / 60 / 60 / 24 =~ 31 days. So the max value for the partition holding the data for september (has also 31 days) will be:
  1346450399 + ( 31 * 24 * 60 * 60)
- An unix to date calculator can be found here: http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

### 2. Rewrite the query

Because the "OR" in your WHERE block, the optimizer will choose not to use the index defined.
Try to split the query in 2 selects, and make an union.

```
SELECT 
    traffic.time, 
    SUM(traffic.bytesin), 
    SUM(traffic.bytesout) 
FROM 
    traffic 
WHERE traffic.type LIKE 'v4_assignment' 
    AND type_id IN (1,2,3,4)
    AND traffic.time >= 1343772000 AND traffic.time <= 1346450399 
GROUP BY 
    traffic.time
UNION
SELECT 
    traffic.time, 
    SUM(traffic.bytesin), 
    SUM(traffic.bytesout) 
FROM 
    traffic 
WHERE traffic.type LIKE 'v4_host' 
    AND type_id IN (5,6,7,8)
    AND traffic.time >= 1343772000 AND traffic.time <= 1346450399 
GROUP BY 
    traffic.time
ORDER BY 
    traffic.time
```

### 3. New index based on data cardinality

Based on your explain output, I don't see the index beeing used.
Maybe because the optimizer decides that it will be easier (cheaper) to make a full table scan then to follow the index.
Also, in your current index, the first column has a lower cardinality then the next 2 ones. The first column in any index should be the column with the best (max) cardinality.

Create a new index as:

```
MYSQL> CREATE INDEX MTIhai_traffic_idx1 ON traffic(time, type, type_id)
```

Comment: @Steven V: If you need help with the partitioning + automatic generation of ranges, I'll be glad to assist you.

Comment: Thank you @MTIhai for your informing response! I've got a lot of new information to look into but will start with creating the new index since that will take some hours to process. If I need some help I will drop you a msg :)

Comment: The 3 recomandations should be taken as a "group". Just creating the new index (to match the better cardinality) will not quarantee that you'll get a visible optimization.

Do at list R2 + R3 (New index + Query with union).

Also, after you create the index, please post the Explain plan for the query with the union (I have a strange curiosity :) ...)

Comment: The `UNION` query is not equivalent to the original.

Comment: use `UNION ALL` will fix this I suppose?

Comment: No, you'll need `UNION ALL` and another, external `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @ypercuve: Why not ?

Comment: @MTIhai: because for one specific `time`, you may have results from both subqueries. These would be in two rows in your query results, while in one row (and summed up), in the original.

Comment: @ypercuve: Indeed, you are right about the GROUP BY. But the WHERE conditions seem to be pretty "eliminatory -> the 2 individual selects won't have overlapping datasets (Why UNION ALL).

Comment: @MTIhai: OP hasn't provided such info, as far as I can understand.

Comment: @ypercuve: If the OP will decide that the "lots of ids" overlap, you'll be right on more time :). I got distracted for using my own ids list when testing.

Comment: You need `UNION ALL` in case the 1e and 2e query returns .e. (1346450399 150,150), which is possible if in a certain interval exactly the same amount of data has entered and exit the network.
Building the index right now. I will return to this thread after the weekend. @MTIhai and @ypercube, many thanks for now!

Comment: A question about partitioning: Currently the tables are only holding data from one month. So I'm already using some kind of partitioning, but these tables still end up with the ~20M rows. I found that the max amount of partitions is 1024. What would be a sensible partition delta for this table? Daily (+- 30 parts/month) weekly (+- 4 parts/month)?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest a compound index on `(time, type, type_id, bytes_in, bytes_out)`.

If the `(type_id, time, type)` combination is unique (what is the primary key of the table by the way?), you could just define the primary key to be `(time, type, type_id)`. Then the clustered index of the table would be this primary key and you wouldn't need the above compound index. Depending what your most common queries are (if they have `group by time` and/or `where time >=? and time <?` like this one), they will have efficiency improvement as they will be able to use the clustered index.

You can also rewrite the query like this

- using `=` instead of `LIKE` and
- combining `GROUP BY` with `ORDER BY` (MySQL proprietary syntax which may improve efficiency):

  ```
  SELECT t.time, SUM(t.bytesin), SUM(t.bytesout) 
  FROM traffic AS t 
  WHERE ( t.type = 'v4_assignment' AND t.type_id IN (231, between 20 to 100 ids,265)
       OR t.type = 'v4_host' AND t.type_id IN (131, ... a lot of ids... ,1506)
        ) 
      AND t.time >= 1343772000 AND t.time < 1346450399 
  GROUP BY t.time ASC ;
  ```

---

**Update + correction**

When you have defined no `PRIMARY` and no `UNIQUE` index on an (InnoDB) table, a hidden 6-byte column is created and used as the clustered index of the table.

So, it may be better to explicitely define a 4-byte auto-incremented integer column and use it in combination with the `time` column (or all the 3 column above) as a `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key. For no other purpose but to have a clustered index that is useful for your queries:

```
ALTER TABLE traffic
  ADD COLUMN
    traffic_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST,
  ADD CONSTRAINT traffic_PK 
    PRIMARY KEY (time, type, type_id, traffic_id) 
  ADD INDEX traffic_id_IDX (traffic_id) ;
```

or (to have a narrower primary key):

```
ALTER TABLE traffic
  ADD COLUMN
    traffic_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST,
  ADD CONSTRAINT traffic_PK 
    PRIMARY KEY (time, traffic_id), 
  ADD INDEX traffic_id_IDX (traffic_id) ;
```

---

**another suggestion**:

Both of these clustered indices are roughly equivalent to the `(time, type, type_id, bytes_in, bytes_out)` suggested at the beginning.

The only other index that might perform better is the `(type, type_id, time, bytes_in, bytes_out)`. But it depends on how may `type_id` are on these lists and what percentage of the data they refer to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
The table does not have a unique key, since we are measuring traffic on multiple location of our network, multiple records with a certain type-type_id combination can be inserted per time interval.
As for the LIKE, I agree that the = is more convenient, but since I don't use any wildcards, I assume MySQL will optimize this.

Comment: Can you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE traffic ;` and add the output at the question? (or that's what you done already?)

Comment: Indeed, the Show Create is what you see underneath the "the table Create:".

Comment: Is it correct, for what I've seen so far, that InnoDb does not accept combined primary keys with autoincrement columns? If so,I think your proposed index will only work with MyISAM?

Comment: No, it should work fine with InnoDB, too.

Comment: Can you add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output, now, after the changes?

Comment: Aye!
Currently changing my index from `(time, type, type_id, id)` to `(time, type_id, type, id)` since type_id has more distinct records. Hoping for the best, and will keep you posted!

Comment: And the answer is... No. The new index makes the query slower by a factor 3. Too bad, just as I started to think I was getting something of this black magic indexes stuff...

Comment: I don't think you added the index in my answer.

Comment: What makes your think I didn't? The `create table` output in the update section is not correct? About my last post, at first, I used your long key suggestion. Than I thought that swapping the type and type_id fields may improve the key even more, but it didn't. So I'm around 30secs now. To improve speed even more I think I will try the partitioning technique suggested by @MTIhai. Or do you think fiddling with the key can improve speed?

Comment: Did you really? What did you define as the Primary key?

Comment: Oh, am I not getting something here? :P Prim key: `PRIMARY KEY (`time`,`type`,`type_id`,`traffic_id`)` with the traffic_id field as a auto increment column. Isn't this what you suggested?

Comment: Oh ok, my bad. I just read the second update.

Comment: You may want to to try a `(type, type_id, time, bytes_in, bytes_out)` index (non-clustered, simple). But I'm not very optimistic on this.